# How to pass a specific model field to views' functions or methods?

Tags: python, django, model, view

I'm using Django 1.8 . I have model called Article with an `article_url` field. I want to pass this url in views to scrape it. How can I do it?

## models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length = 250)
    article_url = models.URLField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

from .models import Article

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published articles."""
        return Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

def detail(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)

    html = Article.article_url
    read = requests.get(html)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(read.content)
    links = soup.find_all("a")

    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'article': article, 'links':link})
```

I think it might be something like this, but it doesn't work. Actually I don't know how to pass a specific model field, not all of objects, to a view function or method.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. What is that requests/soup stuff doing at the class level in DetailView? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?? What will be rendered via this DetailView and to which template?

Comment: you need to read the docs and maybe follow the Django tutorial first (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/ ...writing your first view is in Part 3). just typing random bits of code into a .py file isn't going to get you anywhere

Comment: I've some articles which I'm going to scrape using Beautifulsoup and Requests library. Requests accept url's it's like urllib. So the point here is to pass the url field to the view and then I'll be able to show the data achieved using scrapper tool in detail page of each article. It's not a random bits of code. I've followed django docs, but it didn't mention how to pass "a specific model field to views". it's only talking about the whole objects.

Comment: Is the problem comes from the idea putting this in the class level in DetailView? Will that be ok if I use functions instead of methods?

Comment: But why do you care if it's a field or the whole object? You can always access a field on an object with the dot notation.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. When I set html  variable to  Article.article_url , Django raise an error: type object 'Article' has no attribute 'article_url'
All I want to know is what's the correct way to write it? so it doesn't get it as an attribute, but as a field.

Comment: Then please show the actual code where you are doing that. The code you have shown would not raise that error, even if it made any sense.

Comment: I've completed the code. I've decided to use function views so things are more readable for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem using this piece of code in views:

```
def detail(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)

    html = article.article_url
    read = requests.get(html)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(read.content)
    links = soup.find_all("a")

    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'article': article, 'links':links})
```

I've tried to define article variable and assign an article reading the article_id from url. Then call its field article_url using dot "." notation easily.